# Self join a table and include the joining columns in both queries as single column

Tags: sql, datetime, pivot, full-outer-join

**So This is my table**

```
Machine No | Cut off Date | status    | event number
================================================
        12 | 01-DEC-2018  | Pending   | 8888
        23 | 01-DEC-2018  | Available | 9999
        12 | 01-DEC-2019  | Available | 8888
        23 | 01-DEC-2019  | Available | 9999
        66 | 01-DEC-2018  | Pending   | 6666
```

**Expected result**:
cy(Current Year)- 2018
ly(Last Year)-2017

```
Machine_No |  cy_status   | cy_event number|ly_status |ly_event_number
==================================================================
   12      |  Pending     |  8888          |Available | 8888
   23      |  Available   |  9999          |Available | 9999
   66      |  NULL        |  NULL          |Pending   | 6666
```

**My Current Query and Result:**

```
    SELECT  cy.Machine_No AS Mac_No, ly.Machine_No AS Mac_no, 
    CY_EVENT_NUM, CY_STATUS,
        LY_EVENT_NUM,
        LY_STATUS from
         (      SELECT
                  machine_number AS Machine_No, EVENT_NUMBER AS 
    CY_EVENT_NUM, STATUS AS CY_STATUS
        FROM
          center c
        WHERE
          cut_off_date = '01-DEC-2018'
        AND machine_number IN ('6666', '7777', '8888', '9999')) cy 
    FULL OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT
          machine_number AS Machine_No , EVENT_NUMBER AS 
    LY_EVENT_NUM, STATUS AS LY_STATUS
        FROM
          center c1
        WHERE
          cut_off_date = '01-DEC-2017'
        AND machine_number IN ('6666', '7777', '8888', '9999') )ly 
    on  
    cy.Machine_No= ly.Machine_No'''
```

**Result**:

```
Mac_No|Mac_No|cy_status     |cy_event number |ly_status|ly_event_number
=====  =====    ======        ==============   ========  =========
   12 | NULL |  Pending     |  8888          |Available| 8888
   23 | NULL |  Available   |  9999          |Available| 9999
  NULL| 66   |  NULL        |  NULL          |   NULL  | 7777
```

I cy.Mac_no and ly.Mac_no in same column.

Can someone help me achieve this?

Comment: `coalesce(cy.Machine_No, ly.Machine_No)`

Comment: You have hard-coded 2018 and 2017 as the last and previous last years.  Is this what you want?  Or do you want a more generic solution should this query run in the future in _any_ year?  Also, are you using MySQL or Oracle?  They are not the same thing.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using, `mysql` or `oracle`? I removed both conflicting tags, plus add only the relevant one.

Comment: shonal k, @GMB might removed one tag to much, it might be that you are really using Oracle database can you confirm this? The MySQL tag was not wrong anyway as MySQL never did support `FULL JOIN` syntax..

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular formatted initialization. PS Isolate the first unexpected/misunderstood subexpression & its input & output & find your misunderstanding.

Comment: What if there are two records for 2017 and one for 2018?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your query can be simplified by using conditional aggregation, as follows:

```
select 
    machin_no,
    max(case when extract(year from cut_off_date) = 2018 then status end) cy_status,
    max(case when extract(year from cut_off_date) = 2018 then event_number end) cy_event_number,
    max(case when extract(year from cut_off_date) = 2017 then status end) ly_status,
    max(case when extract(year from cut_off_date) = 2017 then event_number end) ly_event_number
from center
group by machine_no
```

The way you handle dates is not very clear to me, so I based the query on just the year (either cut_off_date is `2017`, or `2018`).

If you need to filter on an exact date, then you can change the conditional maxs as follows:

```
max(case when cut_off_date = to_date('2018-12-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') then status end) cy_status,
... and so on ...
```

The above expression assumes that you are using oracle.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is just to have one column, you can try this :

```
SELECT 
    IFF(cy.Machine_No IS NULL, ly.Machine_No, cy.Machine) AS Machine_No, 
    [... rest of your query]
```